# How to remove blank line at the end of the text here

Tags: php, arrays, file

**I use this array_diff for two text but I cant remove blank line using these preg_replaces at the and of the text lines**

```
$result = preg_replace('/^[ \t]*[\r\n]+/m', '', $result);
$result =  preg_replace('/[\r\n]+$/', '', $result);
```

**I should not delete PHP.EOL but It makes a blank line. what should I do?**

```
<?php
$new = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('new.txt').PHP_EOL);
$old = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('old.txt').PHP_EOL);
$result = array_diff($new, $old);

$output= fopen("Output.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
foreach($result as $value){
fwrite($output, $value.PHP_EOL); }

?>
```

**example of output.txt**

```
4. data
3. data
2. data
1. blank line
```

Comment: I think $result = trim($result); must be enough.

Comment: check this [trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp)

Comment: It doesn't work.Did you try it any?

Comment: https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/190472-open-txt-file-remove-all-blank-lines-and-save-txt-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different approach:

```
$new = file('new.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$old = file('old.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$result = array_diff($new, $old);
file_put_contents('Output.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $result));
```

- Read the files into an array with `file()` stripping the newlines `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` and skipping empty lines `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`
- Run `array_diff()` on the arrays
- `implode()` the result array on a newline and write it to the output file